# How does one turn a Gridview Row clickable which open a modalpopup in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How does one turn a Gridview Row clickable which open a modalpopup in C#?

I have a gridview with several columns. Each row (the entire width of the row) needs to be clickable which onclick opens a modalpopupextender displaying a popup panal with detailed info on the row.

I have the modalpopupextender & panal working properly when an ImageButton is clicked. However I am removing the ImageButton and replacing its functionality with the row onClick.

I appreciate your time!

Comment: I am very new to ASP.NET/C# - this website I have developed is my first ASP project. To be brutally honest, I actually had this very functionality implemented and working during one of the early versions of the website but was replaced by the ImageButton. I did not come up with the codebehind myself but found an example online through Google.com - I have not been able to relocate it after 2 days of searching.

Comment: I tried something like: e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] ... but could not reference the modalpopupextender1.show(); control/function.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the `SelectionMode` property to FullRowSelect.

You could use the `SelectionChanged` event to determine the current row selected.

```
GridView.SelectedRows[0].Index
```

will give you the index of the selected row.  You will have to be sure MultiSelect is disabled as well.

So you have the index of the row selected, so now open whatever form needs opened depending on this index

Comment: Could you provide an example? I am very new to ASP.NET. I remember the function I used previously had nested for loops which set the same attribute for each cell in a row, which opened the ModalPopupExtender.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

[Edit Update GridView With Ajax ModalPopUpExtender Example](http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2012/07/edit-update-gridview-modalpopupextender.html)

This Example explains How To Edit Update GridView Rows Records With **Ajax ModalPopUpExtender** In Asp.Net Using C# and VB.NET.

Comment: I have used Google to find pleanty of examples like this where they have buttons which open the MPE. However I am trying to bind a ModalPopupExtender.Show() to clicking a GridView row.